# MS Project - VBA - Changing resource type

Tags: vba, types, resources, ms-project

Sorry if the question has been answered but I looked a bit on the site and it has helped in many ways already !

I was asked to do in VBA some programming to transfer data into MS Project.

I managed to do it all except for one thing, when I create a resource, Project automatically describes it as a Work Type and some of mine are actually Material Type.

I then thought of changing it after creating the resource and assign it to a task

My bit of problematic code is the following

```
Set NR = .Resources.Add(name:=tmpTxt)
.Resources(k).Type = pjResourceTypeMaterial
.Resources(k).Assignments.Add TaskID:=j
```

When I run it I don't have any error message, but in the resource view on MS Project the Type hasn't changed...

I would be very grateful if any of you can help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there some code you haven't included in your extract that associates NR with .Resources(k)?  It looks like you have created a new material resource and tried to set the resource type of some other existing resource to "Material".  Can you please include the with  . . . end with construct?

Without seeing more of the problem I'm not completely sure what you are having trouble with but assuming you are referencing the ActiveProject all you need to do to create a new Material type resource is:

```
Set NR = Activeproject.Resources.Add (name := "A New Resource")

NR.Type = pjResourceTypeMaterial
```